# The center & radius of the largest circle touching two parabolas $y^2=4x$ and $x^2=4y$.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Find the center & radius of the largest circle touching two parabolas $y^2=4x$ and $x^2=4y$ in the bounded region.

Since the two parabolas are reflections of each other about the y=x line, the center of the circle must lie on the y=x line. Assuming it (h,h) and considering tangency is very lengthy. Is there a shorter and better approach?

Solved it actually. Assuming a point $(t^2,2t)$ and taking maximum distance of y=x gives t=1, point of contact (1,2), center (3/2,3/2) and radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: So does the touching have to be tangental? Are there some other constraints given? After the intersection at $(x,y)=(4,4)$ it looks like you should be able to let the radius grow without bound. Similarly, it looks like before the intersection at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ you can also let the radius grow without bound.

Comment: I forgot to mention it has to touch internally in the bounded area

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: The largest circle touches both parabolas at the endpoints of a diameter, which is then perpendicular to line $y=x$. The points of contact are then those points of the parabolas where $y'=1$.

Comment: FYI: A circle with center $(3/2,3/2)$ with radius of $1/2$ doesn't intersect either of the curves you gave.

Comment: Sorry, its $1/sqrt(2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tangent circle with center $O(h,h)$ touches the parabola $y=2\sqrt{x}$ at $P_1(x_1,x_2)$ then it touches the parabola $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$ at $P_2(x_2,x_1)$. Right?

For the largest circle, the slope of the tangent line at $P_1(x_1,x_2)$ which is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}}$ must be equal to $1$. Right? So, we have $P_1=(1,2)$, $P_2=(2,1)$ and their average $O=(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2})$ ($h=\frac{3}{2}$).

The circle is $(x-\frac{3}{2})^2+(y-\frac{3}{2})^2=\frac{1}{2}.$